# How to free a dynamically allocated string divided into a matrix?

Tags: c

I have a malloced char *str.

```
char *str = strdup("first\nsecond\nthird\nfourth");
```

I have a matrix char **content.

```
char **content;
```

My objective is to cut str replacing '\n' by '\0' and put each first address after every '\0' in my matrix in order. The following code works:

```
int      count_lines(char *str, char **content)
{
  int    len;

  if (content)
    content[0] = str;
  len = 0;
  while (str && *(str++))
    {
      if (*str && *(str - 1) == '\n')
        {
          len++;
          if (content)
            {
              *(str - 1) = 0;
              content[len] = str;
            }
        }
    }
  if (content)
    content[len + 1] = 0;
  return (len + 1);
}

void   test()
{
  char **content;
  int  lines;

  lines = count_lines(str, NULL);
  content = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (lines + 1));
  count_lines(str, content);
}
```

> Then, content[0] contains "first", contant[1] contains "second" and
>   [contant[2] contains "third" and contant[3] contains "fourth".

Now my problem is the following one: I got an error when I try to free from the first address. I dont know if what I do brokes the memory or idk.. Help please, how to free this if possible.

Comment: How exactly did you attempt to free the memory?

Comment: Where is the part that frees the content?

Comment: @LPs: You probably mean `strchr()`, don't you?

Comment: I try to free each element from 0 to 3 in this example.

Comment: And i get : Aborted (Core drump)

Comment: Well, I think you should be using just `free( content )` then. That's because you allocated it as a single block of memory (you called `malloc` just once)

Comment: You only have one allocated block of memory. Putting '\0' at some places does not change anything. Only free first block `content [0]` and `content` itself.

Comment: @Gerhardh No I don't, but still wrong ;)  [strok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) to tokenize the string.

Comment: @LPs You mean `strtok` ;)

Comment: i dont need this, i wanna do it myself

Comment: @LPs No, `strtok` is a bad idea as it changes the string. When the function is called the second time, it will not work any more.

Comment: @Gerhardh exacly what OP code is doing... ;)

Comment: @LPs: No. He first passes content==NULL and no memory is altered. In the second call content != NULL. If you uses strtok to find all the '\n' this would already be done at the first call.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to free the "substring" you split, but you didn't really split them. You only stored pointers of chars inside a string. So you cannot free them as far as you don't strdup strings into your double pointer.

Comment: _I try to free each element from 0 to 3 in this example._ It is not possible to release only part of the secured memory.

Comment: @Romain-p What is this code trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

When you alloc() memory, the system keeps track of the size of the block you allocated - when freeing, the system frees the same amount was allocated.
So, if you use only one malloc(), you can free() only once - any pointer pointing into the area now freed, gets invalidated.

Hence, you need a free() for "str", and a free() for "content". After freeing str, all the pointers in "content" get invalid, but you must free "content" itself. Or, free "content" first and "str" later.

Answer (score 0):

You have to malloc each of these words. 1 free == 1 malloc. Please paste the code where u try to free

Comment: Or allocate it once, and free it once - that's simpler

Comment: hm no you didn't understand my way